# Is there any closed form for this series?

Tags: polynomials, power-series

It's a power series that I found during the computation for my research.

\begin{equation*}
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}x^{n-k}(-1)^k.
\end{equation*}

Without the annoying term of $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$, it is clearly simplified to $(x-1)^n$ due to [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).

Isn't there any name for this series? Can I simplify it as a closed-form polynomial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write it this way: $$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}x^{n-k}(-1)^k
= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(-1)^k\frac{d^k}{dx^k} (x^n)
= \left(I-\frac d{dx}\right)^n x^n
$$

Comment: Interesting. I found out that it's an [associated Laguerre polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AssociatedLaguerrePolynomial.html). By the way, would you recommend a textbook or reference on how to handle differentiation as a linear map? I don't have much background on this field and I need to learn myself on this topic.

Comment: I don't think there is much to know about on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

It can be rewritten as $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}^2k!x^{n-k}(-1)^k$, and, unless you're willing to accept [hypergeometric functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) as closed form, the answer is *no*. My advice would be for you to try and approximate it asymptotically.

Comment: To be honest,I dont understand the other answer.

Comment: Differentiation is a linear map; the identity map is a linear map; linear maps form a ring, so $(I-d/dx)^n$ is a well defined linear map. The series given above is what $(I-d/dx)^n$ maps $x^n$ to.

Comment: @Sabyasachi ? why don't you comment on my answer?

Comment: @mookid i upvoted anyway. it looked legit.